# Prove a Matrix Property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I'm stuck with the following problem.

Let be $W\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ matrix, $n\geq 2$. $W$ is such that:

- $W_{ij}\geq 0$ for all $0\leq i,j\leq n$.
- $W_{ii}=0$ for all $0\leq i\leq n$.
- $W$ is symmetric.
- Let be $w_i=\sum_{j=1,\dots,n}W_{ij}$, then $0<w_i<1$.

Let be $M$ inverse matrix of $\mathbb{I}_n-W$, where $\mathbb{I}_n$ is the identity matrix of size $n$. Let be $W^{(-i)}$ a square matrix obtained by removing  the $i^{th}$-column and $i^{th}$-row from $W$. So let be $M^{(-i)}$ inverse matrix of $\mathbb{I}_{n-1}-W^{(-i)}$.
I've also to prove the following equation:

$$M_{nj}M_{nk}=M_{nn}(M_{jk}-M_{jk}^{(-n)})\text{,}$$
for all $k\ne n \ne j$.

Thanks to last property and Perron-Frobenius theorem I've proved that $M$ and $M^{(-i)}$ are well-defined. But I'm not able to prove the equation above.
Even an hint should be helpful.

Thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Write $W$ in block form
$$W = \begin{bmatrix} W^{(-n)} & v \\ v^T & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
where $v$ is a certain vector. Then
$$I - W = \begin{bmatrix} I - W^{(-n)} & -v \\ -v^T & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$
We can use the inversion formula for block matrices: if $X = (I - W^{(-n)} - v v^T)^{-1}$, then
$$M = \begin{bmatrix} X & Xv \\ v^T X & 1 + v^T X v\end{bmatrix}.$$
Now your formula reduces to the fact that
$$X v v^T X = (1 + v^T X v)(X - (I - W^{(-n)})^{-1})$$
We note that
$$(I - W^{(-n)})^{-1} = (X^{-1} + vv^T)^{-1} = (I + X vv^T )^{-1}X.$$
So it suffices to show that
$$X v v^T X = (1 + v^T X v)(I - (I + X vv^T )^{-1})X.$$
Or
$$X v v^T = (1 + v^T X v)(I - (I + X vv^T )^{-1}).$$
This is actually the formula for the inverse of rank-one pertubation. To derive it, note that the formula is equivalent to
$$(I + X vv^T )^{-1} = I - (1 + v^T X v)^{-1} X v v^T.$$
Or
$$(I + X vv^T )(I - (1 + v^T X v)^{-1} X v v^T) = I.$$
Or
$$I + X vv^T - (1 + v^T X v)^{-1} X v v^T - (1 + v^T X v)^{-1} X vv^TX v v^T = I.$$
Note that
$$X vv^TX v v^T = (v^TX v) X v v^T$$
and simplifying the above gives the proof.

Comment: Thanks!!! This argument also proves that the formula is correct even if $j=k$?

Comment: Another question I didn't get how You've found that last block is $1+v^\text{T}Xv$, cause by using formula taken by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix, i get that should be $1-v^{\text{T}}(I-W^{(-n)})^{-1}v$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am using the formula $D^{-1} + D^{-1}CX^{-1} BD^{-1}$.

Comment: Perfect! Since $B=-v$, shouldn't be $Xv$ instead of $Xv$ on extra diagonal block? However It doesn't change anything for the proof.

Comment: sure I corrected it.